When to use modules, components or stand-alone components in Angular 17?
I'm sorry if this question has been asked already...
I'm pretty new with Angular, so I'm still not sure when to use modules, components or stand-alone components.
Let's say I want to build a relatively small website with a main, a profile and a about us section, does it make sense to separate profile and about us section into separate modules?
Thanks to whoever can help!

Standalone components are relatively new to angular. They solve the problem of having to use "shared" modules, which are modules that contain components that are used in other modules. Sometimes these shared modules really get quite large in size as the app progresses, so we used to make multiple shared modules.
I primarily use modules to create different areas of the application and lazy load them depending on the route the user visits. For your application, I think standalone components will suffice. Creating a module will work too, but those modules will probably just contain one component

If you are new to angular, just use standalone from now on, there is really no big difference.
I myself like modules better ( only cause I'm used to modules architectures ).
but with standalones compoents , it is at least highly recommanded to use standalone pipe and directive for better performance ( usually pipes and directive are inside shared module but the question is , if a certain  compoenent need one pipe, why import all shared component ? ). it is better for performance to only import the specific component/pipe/directive needed and not a whole modules with compoent I don't need .

I would also add to this that a component that is stand alone is more tree shakeable than modules are.  This is really where you get gains in performance.  But having a small site with only a few pages, I would also argue that Angular would not be the correct choice as it is a pretty robust framework that may be overkill for a small site

Now it's more clear, thanks for the explaining!
I know that probably react is a better option for what I need to build, however having a java background, I actually feel more familiar with angular, because if offer a certain structure like java with spring boot does, hence my choice!
